# If $ (\exists K>0)(\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}) \left | f(x) - f(y) \right |\leq K\left | y-x \right |^2 $, then $ (\forall x\in\mathbb{R}) f'(x)=0 $

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I am supposed to decide whether the statement is correct or false.

If $ (\exists K>0)(\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}) \left | f(x) - f(y) \right |\leq K\left | y-x \right |^2 $, then $ (\forall x\in\mathbb{R}) f'(x)=0 $

I thought about using substitution, however, I am not sure how to continue. Thanks!

Comment: please show your work and also include the question in the body as well

Answer (score 2):

Divide by $y-x$ and take limit as $y \to x$. You get $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: Sorry but what should I divide with what?

Comment: @MarkF. The inequality $|f(y)-f(x)|\leq K|y-x|^2$, divide it by $|y-x|$ to get $\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right|\leq K|y-x|$.